# JS Audio - audioBuffer getChannelData to frequency

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, getusermedia, audiobuffer

*bsd*

I am trying achieve pitch detection, and moreover learn some basic audio physics on the way, I am actually really new to this and just trying to understand how this whole thing works...

My question is, What is exactly the audioBuffer and how is the data coming from getChannelData related to frequencies. and how can I extract frequency data from the audioBuffer...

Also, if someone can explain just a bit about sample rates etc. also this would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `AudioBuffer` simply represents an audio resource, namely audio *samples* and additional *information* about the audio.

For instance, you can access the `sampleRate` property of an `AudioBuffer` object to know about the [sampling frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing)#Sampling_rate) of the audio contained in the `AudioBuffer`.

Using `getChannelData` will return you an array of audio samples. At every interval given by the sampling rate, you have a number (comprised between -1.0 and +1.0 for IEEE 32 float audio samples) corresponding to the audio amplitude of the sample. Thus, this array of samples contain *time-domain* audio information.

To do pitch detection, you need to work in the *frequency* domain and to go from the time domain to the frequency domain, you need to use the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform). If you want to understand underlying DSP (digital signal processing) principles, you can use a pure FFT library (for instance, [node-fft](https://github.com/vail-systems/node-fft)). If you just want to achieve a pitch detection, using a turnkey solution such as [pitch.js](https://github.com/audiocogs/pitch.js/) will be easier.

Comment: Additional info: WebAudio API has built-in support for FFT via the [Analyzer node](https://devdocs.io/dom/analysernode).