# Get fft data of a audio file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, audio, browser, fft

In real-time we do this to get the frequency of the audio while audio is playing.

```
Window.onload{
audio.load();
audio.play();
Var context = new audioContext();
Context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
Var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
analyser.fftsize = 512;
Var array = new uintarray(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

Function render(){
RequestAnimationFrame(render);
analyser.getFrequencyBinCount(array);
//Process frequency details here

}
```

I want to get a frequency of an audio clip 30 times a second in nonreal time.
**for example**

```
Var subSecond = 1/30;

Var frequency = getFrequencyAt(64*subSecond);

Function getFrequencyAt(s){
//Logic to get the frequency here
}
```

How can I achieve this efficiently?

Comment: You'd need to get your audio data as an ArrayBuffer, then decode it, then either working directly from an AudioBuffer's channelData, or try to play your AudioBuffer inside an OffscreenAudioContext on which you'd attach an AnalyserNode, (though I'm not sure how well this works across browsers) or even using the new [AudioWorklet API](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#AudioWorklet) but I'm not sure anyone has it working yet)...

Comment: But if I do that I'll be playing the audio right? I don't wanna play the whole audio clip because it'll consume time,the former idea of working on audio buffer,initially I need to read the file to array buffer and decode it to audio after that How can I get the frequency from channel data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397325/js-audio-audiobuffer-getchanneldata-to-frequency

Comment: @Kaiido Thank u very much